# Angular 5 Material-UI dynamic Mat Table from json data

Tags: typescript, angular5, mat-table

I am hitting an api that can will return different JSON's, each meaning a different table.

This is the generic HTML in my compenent.html

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource] = "cols" class="mat-elevation-z8">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let col of cols" [matColumnDef]="col">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ col }} </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element[col] }} </td>
            </ng-container>
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
```

The data I'm getting in my component class

```
getData(){
  this.requestService.getTableData().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.arrData = data as string []; 
       console.log(this.arrData['requestType']);
    },
    error => {
      console.log (error.message);
    }
  )
  this.cols = JSON.parse(this.arrData['responsePayload']);
}
```

the JSON Data I'm finally getting looks like this

```
[
  {
    "Company": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    "Contact": "Maria Anders",
    "Country": "Germany"
  },
....
]
```

this.cols is my data source for the mat-table and it is populating correctly as an array with 6 entries.
I need to make a mat-table out of this, but I keep getting this error

> requestHandler.html:6 ERROR TypeError: name.replace is not a function
>       at MatColumnDef.set name [as name] (table.js:175)
>       at updateProp (core.js:32188)

at

```
       <ng-container *ngFor="let col of cols" [matColumnDef]="col">
```

Can someone point me in the right direction / tell me where I'm going wrong?

Also, if something isn't clear in the question please let me know I'll try explaining again.

Note: I believe there is a solution in making an interface for the JSON data I'm getting, but I will end up making a slightly static HTML for each type of table. I want to keep it generic. Something like a dynamic interface (which can't be done, I think.) [This](https://github.com/jvilk/MakeTypes) is kinda cool though, but I need to be able to do this in runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import MatTableDataSource in your .ts file

```
import {MatTableDataSource} from "@angular/material";
```

define cols as below

```
cols: MatTableDataSource<Any>;
```

and you have to pass array as `MatTableDataSource`

```
 this.cols = new MatTableDataSource(this.arrData['responsePayload']);
```

and also you can use row wise method

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource] = "cols" class="mat-elevation-z8">

       <!-- Company Column -->
       <ng-container matColumnDef="company">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Company </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Company}} </mat-cell>
       </ng-container>

       <!-- Contact Column -->
       <ng-container matColumnDef="contact">
           <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Contact </mat-header-cell>
           <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{row.Contact}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

       <!-- Country Column -->
       <ng-container matColumnDef="country">
           <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Country </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Country}} </mat-cell>
       </ng-container>

       <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
       <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
   </table>
```

Hope this will helps ..!

Comment: I did something similar, and it worked. Now I have new problem. How do I add a paginator for each table dynamically.

Comment: @Bugsy could you please ask it as new question, that will helps others also

Comment: @ Bugsy - u can use `mat-paginator` for that  `this.cols.paginator`  as `mat-paginator` , this will function as Table Paginator

Comment: I did face issues with that approach. I will try uploading a fiddle later.

Comment: @Bugsy  - What is the issue? Can you post the issue in different question then i can help you. Because if i extend the answer here, with that  it will be off topic